# adb pull multiple files

Tags: android, adb

What is the best way to pull multiple files using

```
adb pull
```

I have on my `/sdcard/` 25 files with following name:

```
gps1.trace
gps2.trace
...
gps25.trace
```

Wildcard does not work:

```
adb pull /sdcard/gps*.trace .
```

Comment: I don't use `adb` but from the docs `pull` can be used to pull an entire directory??? If that's the case and these are files generated by your own app then why not write them out to a sub-directory such as `/sdcard/mygpsfiles` and then use `adb pull /sdcard/mygpsfiles`. Would that work?

Comment: Alternatively, I've just tried the File Explorer in the `DDMS` perspective of eclipse and was able to multi-select files from my sdcard and perform a `pull` on them. If you don't use eclipse, DDMS is available as a separate SDK tool.

Comment: `monitor` command works great, should be in `<sdkdir>/tools`!

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use `xargs` and the result of the `adb shell ls` command which accepts wildcards. This allows you to copy multiple files. Annoyingly the output of the `adb shell ls` command includes line-feed control characters that you can remove using `tr -d '\r'`.

Examples:

```
# Using a relative path
adb shell 'ls sdcard/gps*.trace' | tr -d '\r' | xargs -n1 adb pull
# Using an absolute path 
adb shell 'ls /sdcard/*.txt' | tr -d '\r' | sed -e 's/^\///' | xargs -n1 adb pull
```

Comment: actually those are carriage returns which must be filtered, but right idea on an obscure issue

Comment: Here's a slightly improved version that can handle spaces in file names: https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/android/pull_all.sh

Comment: FYI: Windows and DOS use "\r\n" for carriage-return / line-feed pairs (i.e. not "\n\r").

Comment: in my case it failed trying to pull the (correctly obtained) filenames from the android's root directory, to solve it, I used: `adb shell "ls -d /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots/*" | tr '\r' ' ' | xargs -n1 adb pull`

Comment: I had to use `find` instead of `ls` because paths starting with `/` didn't work and ones without `/` returned just filename, without full path. (Windows/msys)

Comment: It's true that the newline in windows is \n\r, but there's no build-in "tr" or "xargs" command in batch.

Comment: See my answer below for a slightly modified version that allows you to pull into remote directories and is slightly more terse

Comment: I found your answer useful, but I wondered why you didn't just do `tr -d '\r'`.

Comment: It doesn't work saying *tr is not recognized as an internal or external command*

Comment: `tr` is an application present in Linux or git bash.

Comment: I wrote a bash function expanding on this answer to allow me to pass in a parameter to combine with the *

`function vids () {
 adb shell 'ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_2022'"$1"'*.mp4' | tr -d '\r' | sed -e 's/^\///' | xargs -n1 adb pull
}`

Usage: vids 1028
Result: Pulls all the videos from 2022/10/28

Comment: Add `-a` at the end of the command, after `adb pull`, to preserve the timestamps in the original files

Answer (score 112):

`adb pull` can receive a directory name instead of at file and it will pull the directory with all files in it.

Pull all your gps traces in /sdcard/gpsTraces

```
adb pull /sdcard/gpsTraces/ .
```

Example of `adb pull` and `adb push` of recursive directories:

```
C:\Test>adb pull /data/misc/test/ .
pull: building file list...
pull: /data/misc/test/test1/test2/test.3 -> ./test1/test2/test.3
pull: /data/misc/test/test1/test2/test.2 -> ./test1/test2/test.2
pull: /data/misc/test/test1/test2/test.1 -> ./test1/test2/test.1
pull: /data/misc/test/test1/test.3 -> ./test1/test.3
pull: /data/misc/test/test1/test.2 -> ./test1/test.2
pull: /data/misc/test/test1/test.1 -> ./test1/test.1
pull: /data/misc/test/test.3 -> ./test.3
pull: /data/misc/test/test.2 -> ./test.2
pull: /data/misc/test/test.1 -> ./test.1
9 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
0 KB/s (45 bytes in 0.093s)

C:\Test>adb push . /data/misc/test/
push: ./test1/test2/test.3 -> /data/misc/test/test1/test2/test.3
push: ./test1/test2/test.2 -> /data/misc/test/test1/test2/test.2
push: ./test1/test2/test.1 -> /data/misc/test/test1/test2/test.1
push: ./test1/test.3 -> /data/misc/test/test1/test.3
push: ./test1/test.2 -> /data/misc/test/test1/test.2
push: ./test1/test.1 -> /data/misc/test/test1/test.1
push: ./test.3 -> /data/misc/test/test.3
push: ./test.2 -> /data/misc/test/test.2
push: ./test.1 -> /data/misc/test/test.1
9 files pushed. 0 files skipped.
0 KB/s (45 bytes in 0.062s)
```

Comment: @kakyo It does work for subfolders for me. check you have the latest ADB from google. (I'm using 1.0.29)

Comment: Yes, I found that it works for non-empty folders in the end. I had some empty folders that didn't get pulled. Also, seems that "push" is non-recursive?

Comment: @kakyo I've added the output of a recursive pull and push to my answer. You are correct about empty folders, they do not get pulled or pushed.

Comment: Beware: with ADB pull the files lose their original modified date.

Comment: @Stan: unless you use the "-a" option as in "adb pull [-a] <remote>... <local>", which according to the help preserves the file timestamp and mode.

Answer (score 28):

`./adb pull /sdcard`  <-- fails

`./adb pull /sdcard/`  <-- works recursively - note the trailing slash

Tested with Nexus 5 and adb downloaded March 2014.

Comment: For me it worked recursively without the final slash, adb version 1.0.32

Answer (score 18):

Parsing the output from 'ls' is generally a bad idea.  Instead, use 'find'.

```
adb shell 'find /sdcard/ -name "gps*.trace" -print0' | xargs -0 -n 1 adb pull
```

[Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: On my machine I needed to use the full path to adb, but otherwise this worked great!

Answer (score 7):

I have created this for Windows boxes, It is very useful to transfer files using wildcards without mounting the filesystem. You can include this script somewhere in your path env.

adbpull.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if %1.==. (
    echo Wilcard parameter is required.
    goto end
)
for /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F in (`adb shell ls %1`) do (
    set text=%%F
    set mfile=!text:~0,-1!
    adb pull "!mfile!"
)
:end
endlocal
```

Example:
`adbpull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_2016*`

Answer (score 6):

Even though `adb pull` command started accepting folder name for the remote parameter, I still prefer to use `tar` command. It provides more flexibility - allows for file name patterns (both *include* and *exclude*), symlink control, preserves file permissions. Since Android 6.0 you can use a built-in. Before that you had to use 3rd-party tools like `busybox`:

```
adb exec-out tar c sdcard/amazonmp3 > amazon.tar
```

Make sure to omit the leading `/` in your path.

Comment: Oh, it didn't work.  tar -tvf tells me that the result doesn't look like a tar archive.  Oh well.

Comment: Very strong way! But the problem is errors/warnings like "tar: removing leading '/' from member names" added to output file. Don't know how to eliminate this.

Comment: I get 1.5KB file on the output.

Comment: Heads up! You need to redirect stderr to somewhere else or you might get a corrupted tar file! See https://askubuntu.com/a/170000 for reason, and at least test if the result file is not corrupted.

Answer (score 5):

[ADBFS a FUSE Filesystem for Android Debug Bridge](http://collectskin.com/adbfs/) if you are using linux or mac

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Windows with Cygwin. But I have to remember this one - very interesting solution !

Answer (score 4):

Directory pull is available on new android tools.
( I don't know from which version it was added, but its working on latest ADT 21.1 )

```
adb pull /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots
pull: building file list...
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110415.jpg -> ./090313-110415.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110412.jpg -> ./090313-110412.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110408.jpg -> ./090313-110408.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110406.jpg -> ./090313-110406.jpg
pull: /sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/090313-110404.jpg -> ./090313-110404.jpg
5 files pulled. 0 files skipped.
61 KB/s (338736 bytes in 5.409s)
```

Answer (score 2):

building on David's answer, I find this to be slightly better:

```
adb shell ls /foo | tr -d '\r' | xargs -n1 adb pull
```

In addition to it being one character less to type (big deal) it doesn't convert the `-r` into a space.  This is a significant difference, as if you try to do

```
adb shell ls /foo/myFile* | tr '\r' ' ' | xargs -i -n1 adb pull {} someDir
```

you'll get error saying

```
remote object '/foo/myFile1 ' does not exist
```

Instead you can do this, which will work:

```
adb shell ls /foo/myFile* | tr -d '\r' | xargs -i -n1 adb pull {} someDir
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell:

`adb shell ls /sdcard/gps*.trace | foreach {adb pull $_}`

Answer (score 0):

Wild cards work in my case, I have been using following simple script to import Whatsapp Images of my virtual device in to my desktop

```
#! /bin/bash
mkdir -p ~/Pictures/Pictures_adb
rm -f ~/Pictures/Pictures_adb/*
cd ~/Pictures/Pictures_adb
adb root
adb shell 'cp /data/media/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp\ Profile\ Photos/* /sdcard/Pictures/;exit'
adb pull /sdcard/Pictures
mv ~/Pictures/Pictures_adb/Pictures/* ~/Pictures/Pictures_adb/
rmdir ~/Pictures/Pictures_adb/Pictures
cd
```

Comment: You use wildcards for cp on Android and not for pull on the host, that's why it works. Nice alternative, though copying to /sdcard/ costs extra memory and leaks private files to sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using `adb exec-out`. For example to get all of today's screenshots you can do:

```
adb exec-out "cd /sdcard/Pictures/Screenshots; tar c Screenshot_20210907*" | tar x
```

This will transfer all of the files inside a temporary tar archive and extract it to your current working directory. Credit is due to https://stackoverflow.com/a/39429196/3347392.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to expand on `David Momenso`'s answer and address the specific part of the question about wildcards. I turned his suggestion into a bash function that will allow for passing in a parameter that will append to the wildcard.

This a bash function that will allow for pulling all videos based on the date, utilizing the passed in parameter and wildcard.

`function vids () { adb shell 'ls /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_2022'"$1"'*.mp4' | tr -d '\r' | sed -e 's/^\///' | xargs -n1 adb pull }`

- `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/VID_2022` is pointing to the Camera folder and has the file prefix that accounts for the current year
- `"$1"` is take the first parameter that comes after the function call

  - `1027` in the example usage `vids 1027`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows `adb.exe` and `gitbash`, even syntax is right, `adb.exe` says it cannot find files if used in `xargs`.

You have to use cmd `for` loop:

```bash
for /f "delims=" %G in ('adb shell find sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20221111*') do adb pull -a "%G"
```

This will download all photos and videos matching the criteria(in my case, taken on the day 2022 Nov 11st).

Find more info googling `for /f` and `linux find`.

---

If you don't have `find` available(Gitbash not installed), a workaround is to move all files you want on phone to another new album and `adb pull` from there. Not a solution but a workaround.

```bash
adb pull -a sdcard/DCIM/new-album . # will pull all photos to a folder called "new-album"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

adb pull $(adb shell ls /storage/9016-4EF8/DCIM/Camera/wildcard*) ./

Answer (score -3):

In Android, there are some folder with associated permissions! Some folder belong to root- or system user.

You guys should change the permissions of those files, folders before doing "adb pull".

The following commands could help:

```
adb shell
su
chmod -R 777 target_folder
exit
...
adb pull /.../target_folder/ . (current local folder)
```