# Transferring binary data over ADB shell (ie fast file transfer using tar)

Tags: android, adb

I've been trying to move files from my android device to my osx machine using something similar to: `adb shell tar -c directory_to_copy | tar -x`. It seems that the remote tar is working but somewhere on the way the file gets corrupted.
After some playing around I've found:

- It seems the adb shell command translates LF to CRLF:

  ```
  % adb shell 'cd /mnt/sdcard;echo hi>a.bin'
  % adb shell 'cd /mnt/sdcard;cat a.bin' | hexdump -C
  00000000  68 69 0d 0a                                       |hi..|
  00000004
  % adb pull /mnt/sdcard/a.bin
  0 KB/s (3 bytes in 0.457s)
  % hexdump -C a.bin
  00000000  68 69 0a                                          |hi.|
  00000003
  ```
- It looks either the server or the daemon are causing that and not the client (see the len=4):

  ```
  % ADB_TRACE=1 adb shell 'cd /mnt/sdcard;cat a.bin'
  [... snip ...]
  system/core/adb/commandline.c::read_and_dump():read_and_dump(): post adb_read(fd=3): len=4
  [... snip ...]
  ```

I would guess that the daemon is doing that sort of translation in the shell command for windows users.

My questions are:

1. wtf? (what does that and for what purpose?)
2. is there any way to tell it (adbd?) to not do that?
3. can anyone think of any creative way to circumvent that (I thought about base64 encoding the data, but I would prefer to avoid that overhead. Also, creating a local file is not an option since my filesystem is quite full)

Thanks!

Comment: it's first time I see reasonable "wtf?" question on SO :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adb isn't doing this on purpose, but it's not smart enough to refrain from allocating a terminal when you give it a command to run; the terminal on the android side is what's cooking the bytes. Instead of

```
adb shell 'cd /mnt/sdcard;cat a.bin' | hexdump -C
```

try doing

```
adb shell 'stty raw; cd /mnt/sdcard;cat a.bin' | hexdump -C
```

This instructs the terminal device not to mangle the bytes at all, but to pass them through.

Comment: "/system/bin/sh: stty: not found"

Comment: Best answer ever, never thought this would be possible!

Comment: Future readers: Definitely check out the later answers below. I think they are more correct than mine, although I'm not sure whether exec-out existed in 2012 when I wrote this one.

Comment: I think it is the best answer because exec-out is very slow if data is huge.

Comment: This no longer works with latest adb :(

Answer (score 15):

Use `adb exec-out <command>` instead of `adb shell`.

Example `adb exec-out cat /data/myfile.txt > localfile.txt`

Comment: Do I need to install something or do I need some specific ADB version to run this "exec-out"? When I try to run "adb exec-out..." it is listing all adb commands options, same when I use some random command like "adb foobar...", which means it does not exists.

Comment: My version is Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.36

Comment: More info about the `adb exec-out` command: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/5d9d434efadf1c535c7fea634d5306e18c68ef1f

Comment: I suspect that exec-out requires an adb on the phone that is new enough to support it, and my recover ROM is not.

Comment: But `adb exec-out` doesn't seem to support stdin... :( There's `adb exec-in`, but you can't do communicate bidirectionally, which is needed for e.g. `rsync`

Comment: Try `adb raw exec:'command'` - it seems to be a bidirectional `adb exec-in/out`

Comment: In my case `adb shell` works faster than `adb exec-out`.

Answer (score 11):

The "stty" trick mentioned in the first answer does not work in general.

For piping the output to the hexdump command on the host side it might be ok. However, for tar (as is mentioned in the subject of the original question) and for many other commands that can accept binary stream input, this does not work. As Fabian Zeindl has pointed out correctly, using 'adb exec-out ...' is the right way to go.

Some examples for transferring the output of tar over ADB:

1. Here it is assumed that the tar executable is found in your path on Android:

   - `adb exec-out 'cd /sdcard; tar -cf - DCIM/' > DCIM.tar`
   - `adb exec-out 'cd /sdcard; tar -cf - DCIM/' | tar -tvf -`
2. Some more complex examples involving compression and the use of busybox:

   - `adb exec-out 'cd /sdcard; /system/xbin/extras/busybox tar -czf - DCIM/' > DCIM.tgz`
   - `adb exec-out 'cd /sdcard; GZIP="-9" /system/xbin/extras/busybox tar -czf - DCIM/' | tar -tvzf -`
   - `adb exec-out 'cd /sdcard; BGZIP2="-9" /system/xbin/extras/busybox tar -cjf - DCIM/' > DCIM.tar.bz2`

Comment: How can I get the tar executable?

Comment: 7Zip is unable to open the DCIM tar file made this way on windows. Maybe the android tar software is broken somehow or exec-out modifies the binary content in windows

Comment: @beppe9000 Probably you were using Powershell, which deliberately converts redirected output in UTF-16 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098771/changing-powershells-default-output-encoding-to-utf-8). If you use the new Powershell Core, or the classic "cmd", it works.