# OutputDataReceived is not equal to the cmd output. Why?

Tags: c#, cmd, redirectstandardoutput

I create the process this way:

```
Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd",
                Arguments = "/C tools\\adb " + serial + command,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
            }
        };
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Then I subscribe to the event:

```
process.OutputDataReceived += Display;
```

I append the data to the StringBuilder:

```
builder.AppendLine(e.Data);
```

Finally i append the StringBuilder text to a RichTextBox.

```
rtb_console.AppendText(builder.ToString());
```

The problem is, that the the output I get is not equal to the output i get with cmd.

E.g.

CMD (correct):

```
Line 1 text text text text
Line 2 text text text text
Line 3 text text text text
```

With C# (wrong):

```
Line 1 text text text text

Line 2 text text text text

Line 3 text text text text
```

I also get the wrong output, when I execute

```
adb logcat -d > output.txt
```

The problem does not occur, if I use StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(), but then I will not get the live output.

I can not find the problem. Can you help me?

Sincerely

Comment: well "stuff > file" blocks standard out, so no you wouldnt see live output, it would be in output.txt .. second, it seems as if its capturing the linefeeds, and then you're writelining them.. (you havent shown how you do that) so.. dont use writeline..

Comment: I do not use "stuff > file" in the program. I subscribe to the event. Event fires -> data is written to StringBuilder -> append data to RichTextBox

Comment: The text you received in your OutputDataReceived event handler already includes the line terminator.  AppendLine() adds *another* one.  Use Append() instead.

Comment: Thank you both for help. Found the answer. See the post below.

Answer (score -2):

Well, finally I found the answer.

The key is, to use shell commands with no pty. Pty mangles the binary output.

Instead of

```
adb shell ls
```

use

```
adb exec-out ls
```

More information:

[Read binary stdout data from adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/5d9d434efadf1c535c7fea634d5306e18c68ef1f

[Transferring binary data over ADB shell (ie fast file transfer using tar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689511/transferring-binary-data-over-adb-shell-ie-fast-file-transfer-using-tar)