# How to copy all files to my PC using ADB tool?

Tags: android, adb

This command `adb pull` to copy files from your phone to my computer. How can I use it to copy all files in the android device into a folder on my computer?

Comment: What do you mean of all files?

Comment: So the device is rooted?

Comment: A bit related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074671/adb-pull-multiple-files

Comment: Exact match : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050925/how-do-i-adb-pull-all-files-of-a-folder-present-in-sd-card

Answer (score 8):

give only the directory name it will copy the whole file. The dot at the end is the destination directory of my host pc (. means present working directory)

```
adb pull "/data/data/com.pkg.test/files/" .
```

output

```
 /data/data/com.pkg.test/files/: 20 files pulled. 0 files skipped. 4.9 MB/s (31176666 bytes in 6.062s)
```

Comment: This worked for me.