# why adb shell doesn't support wildcard?

Tags: android, shell, adb, wildcard

I'm trying to download the files from my android device with adb shell command, and when I typed:

> /adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*2014*.jpg ~/Downloads/temp

and got the feedback as below:

> remote object '/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/*.jpg' does not exist

so, I'm wondering why does adb shell not support wildcard as a common sense with linux shell script environment ?

Thanks of all ....

Comment: See this topic, use wildcard in `adb pull` ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074671/adb-pull-multiple-files