# Use ADB Pull to pull files based on filename

Tags: android

I am trying to use ADB to pull files based on their filename containing certain characters.  Phone is not rooted HTC One.  PC is Windows 7.

I found this question: [adb pull multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074671/adb-pull-multiple-files)

The original code in that thread was:

```
adb shell ls /sdcard/gps*.trace | tr "\n\r" " " | xargs -n1 adb pull
```

I have modified it to:

```
ADB shell ls /mnt/sdcard/dcim/100Media/IMAG07* | tr "\r\n" " " | xargs -n1 adb pull \HTC2
```

When I run the code, I get an error that "'tr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What am I doing wrong?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's no build-in "tr" or "xargs" command in windows.
Here's my working batch script for windows. Modify the pattern and save it as a ***.bat file, copy it to the local directory(in your case the HTC2 folder), and double click it or run it in the cmd window in this folder.

[image: pull_multiple_files]

```
@echo off
rem ======== Modify this line to your pattern =====
adb shell ls /sdcard/*.png >_temp
rem =================================================

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (_temp) do (
    echo %%i>_temp
    set /p file=<_temp
    echo pulling file: !file!
    adb pull !file!
)
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
del _temp
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.  Here is exactly what I am using: `@echo off
rem ======== Modify this line to your pattern =====

C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/dcim/100Media/IMAG07*.jpg >_temp

rem =================================================


setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f %%i in (_temp) do (

    echo %%i>_temp

    set /p file=<_temp

    echo pulling file: !file!

    adb pull !file!

)

setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

del _temp `

Comment: run C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/dcim/100Media/IMAG07*.jpg   in the cmd windows, what is the output? @luv951

Comment: The output is a list of all my jpg files between 700 and 799.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help!  I figured out what I was doing to make your code work.  I am very new to this (5 days ago downloaded SDK for the first time) so it took a bit for me to work through the code.  I added cmd \k at the end so the command prompt would stay open and I could verify what it had done.

```
rem@echo off
rem ======== Modify this line to your pattern =====
C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/dcim/100Media/IMAG09*.jpg >_temp
rem =================================================

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in (_temp) do (
    echo %%i>_temp
    set /p file=<_temp
    echo pulling file: !file!
    C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platform-tools\adb pull !file! 
)
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
del _temp
cmd /k
```