# adb pull multiple files with the same extension

Tags: android, cmd, adb

How can we pull multiple files with the same extension by using "abd" command?

More details, I know that we can use command

```
adb pull sdcard/folder target-folder
```

to get all file of the folder.

I use this command to filter file in the adb shell.

```
ls -lR sdcard/folder | grep "ext"
```

But I want to filter some files with the same extension and pull them. 
So now, how can we combine two commands?

Comment: This link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050925/how-do-i-adb-pull-all-files-of-a-folder-present-in-sd-card> might help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
adb shell ls sdcard/folder/*.ext | tr '\r' ' ' | xargs -n1 adb pull
```

See [adb pull multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074671/adb-pull-multiple-files)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I run this command, I get this: /system/bin/sh: tr: not found

/system/bin/sh: xargs: not found

Comment: Are you sure you are not executing this command while being in shell session?

Comment: In fact, I already read the link in your answer, but it doesn't work with me. When I go to the shell of device by "adb shell", I type "tr --help" and "xargs --help", it returns the results in my command.

Comment: The thing is that I don't really understand why it's trying to locate tr and xargs on your device instead of you local machine. "adb shell ls sdcard/folder/*.ext" command returns the result back to your terminal. If the command is executed while not being in adb shell session, then it should work out. Make sure that you are not executing the provided command while being in the shell session.

Comment: You can see what I tried [image](http://imgur.com/s9YI71g). In fact, I can run this command in the virtual machine which is ubuntu OS. But it doesn't work on Windows. Moreover, do you know where can it put the destination folder in this command?

Comment: Ah, Windows. I recommend you to use cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/) for such purposes. Regarding the destination folder you can define it this way: adb shell ls sdcard/folder/*.ext | tr '\r' ' ' | xargs -J % -n1 adb pull % <detination_folder>

Comment: Good answer but, considering the comments, a bit terse. It might be worth you expanding on your answer to clarify that the command is for Linux (perhaps MacOS too?) and should be issued from a shell command prompt (terminal window) and assumes that the `adb`, `tr` and `xargs` tools are installed and accessible in the environment's path.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, even with gitbash installed (so `find` and `xargs` available), you have to use CMD `for` to iterate the file list.

```bash
for /f "delims=" %G in ('adb shell find sdcard/DCIM/Camera/20221111*') do adb pull -a "%G"
```

This will download all photos and videos matching the criteria(in my case, taken on the day 2022 Nov 11st).

Find more info googling `for /f` and `linux find`.