# how to adb pull folder with wildcard

Tags: android, shell, adb

Basically, I dump all data into the directory `'sdcard/2019-07-xx-xx` and there are subdirectories in `2019-07-xx-xx`. The Folder is named after the timestamp when dumping data, now I run the command:

```
adb pull '/sdcard/2019-07*'
```

but it prompted:

```
adb: error: failed to stat remote object 'sdcard/2019-07*': No such file or directory
```

who can help me out?

Comment: Pull does not accept wildcard. So, you can find a workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250068/4860513

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Example:

```
for days in 0{1..9} 1{0..9} 2{0..9} 3{0..1}; do 
   adb shell echo "\$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/2019-07-$days/" 
done
```

### Gives us below output:

```
/sdcard/2019-07-01/
/sdcard/2019-07-02/
/sdcard/2019-07-03/
/sdcard/2019-07-04/
/sdcard/2019-07-05/
......
```

## Final: *You can copy and paste*

#### - *don't forget to change source_path and dates if needed - Notice the trial slash*:

```
for days in 0{1..9} 1{0..9} 2{0..9} 3{0..1}; do
   adb pull "\$EXTERNAL_STORAGE/2019-07-$days/" ~/source_path
done
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation "adb pull" command can pull file or directory from your device. There is no support for a wildcard.

But you can use xargs to accomplish this. Just check [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074671/adb-pull-multiple-files)